# How i can to store a set of components for some separate vue apps?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm writing own project via Vue.js

I have several applications that include a set of common components and unique components.

I want to be able to configure configs for these applications, in which I could specify the necessary components and data for them, like this:

```
"load": [
    "Core.vue",
    "Accordion.vue",
    "Buttons.vue",
    "Table.vue",
    "etc"
],
"components": {
    "table": {
        "name": "title"
    },
    "accordion": {
        "tabs": {
            "tab1": {
                "name": 'tab1'
            },
            "tab2": {
                "name": 'tab2'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then components take this data and show it:

```
<template>
  <div> {{ name }} </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: "Table",
    props: ['name']
  }
</script>
```

I think it can be JSON or .yml file (or any other format), but i don't understand how to process them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you are looking for [dynamic component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html) .
that way, you can keep the components you need in some json file, import it to the parent component and dynamically create the children, for example, if you have a `jsonMap.json` file:

```
{
   landingPage:{
      banners:['child1','child2']
   }
}
```

then `landingPage.vue`:

```
<template>
<div>
  <component v-for="(banner,index) in getBanners" :is="banner" :key="index"</component>
   //this is a dynamic component. the 'is' attribute determine what it will be. 
</div>
</template>

<script>
import jsonMap from 'path/to/jsonMap'
import child1 from 'path/to/shared/components/child1.vue'
import child2 from 'path/to/shared/components/child2.vue'
import child3 from 'path/to/shared/components/child3.vue'

export default {

  name: 'landingPage',
  components:{child1,child2,child3},

  methods:{
    getBanners(){
      return jsonMap[this.name].banners
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

landing page will render 2 banners- according to the jsonMap.
note that despite you must import and register your components, that can not be done dynamically.

Comment: But what if I have separate component props? How I can to forward necessary props?
And it necessary to import all of the components to the main component? They will be included in one .js file after the build?

Comment: not very elegant solution, but you can send all possible props (unneeded props are ignored). and yes, you must register your component ahead of time. (you can import them to a mixin (https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html) so it wont mess your component)

Answer (score 0):

I would make a component called `ModuleLoader.vue` in that component import all of your components in the `load` array. Then make a dynamic component that takes a computed property or just a prop to load the component.

App.vue

```
<ModuleLoader
  v-for="(module, index) in modules"
  :key="`ModuleLoader_${index}`"
  v-bind="module"
/>
```

ModuleLoader.vue

```
<component
  :is="moduleData.type"
  v-bind="moduleData.content"
/>
```

You'll need a `ModuleData` prop and you'll have to import the components you're loading into this file

Check out this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/caseyjoneal/tjxuwmk8/24/)